# $f(\pmb A \cup \pmb B) = f(\pmb A \cap \pmb B) + f( (\pmb A \cup \pmb B ) \setminus (\pmb A \cap \pmb B) ) , \forall \pmb A ,\pmb B \in \pmb {P(M)}$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Let $\pmb M$ be a set with $n$ elements and $\pmb {P(M)}$ the set which contains all the subsets of $\pmb M$. Find the functions $f : \pmb {P(M)} \rightarrow \{0,1,2,...,n\} $ which check the following properties :

a)$f(\pmb A) \ne 0$, for $\pmb A \ne \emptyset$

b)$f(\pmb A \cup \pmb B) = f(\pmb A \cap \pmb B) + f( (\pmb A \cup \pmb B ) \setminus (\pmb A \cap \pmb B) ) , \forall \pmb A ,\pmb B \in \pmb {P(M)}$

**My attempt :**

If we make $\pmb A = \pmb B = \emptyset$ in b) we get that : $f(\emptyset) = 2f(\emptyset) \implies f(\emptyset)=0$.Now let's consider the subsets $\pmb A,\pmb B$ such that $\pmb B \subset \pmb A \implies \pmb A \cup \pmb B= \pmb A , \pmb A \cap \pmb B= \pmb B $ and $ (\pmb A \cup \pmb B ) \setminus (\pmb A \cap \pmb B) = \pmb A \setminus \pmb B$.Putting this in b) we get $f(\pmb A) = f(\pmb B) + f(\pmb A \setminus \pmb B) ,\forall \pmb A ,\pmb B \in \pmb {P(M)} , \pmb B \subset \pmb A $. So for a subset $\{i_1,i_2\}$ where $i_1,i_2 \in \pmb M , i_1 \ne i_2$ we get that $f(\{i_1,i_2\})=f(\{i_1\})+f(\{i_2\}) , \forall i_1,i_2 \in \pmb M , i_1 \ne i_2 $ Now for a subset with 3 different elements $\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}$ and the set $\{i_3\}$ we have : $f(\{i_1,i_2 , i_3\})=f(\{i_1,i_2\})+f(\{i_3\}) = f(\{i_1\})+f(\{i_2\}) + f(\{i_3\}) , \forall i_1,i_2,i_3 \in \pmb M , i_1 \ne i_2 \ne i_3 $ . Using a similar reasoning we can easily prove by induction that :

c) $f(\{i_1,i_2,...,i_k\}) = f(\{i_1\}) + f(\{i_2\}) + ... + f(\{i_k\}) , \forall i_1,i_2,...,i_k \in \pmb M , i_1 \ne i_2 \ne ... \ne i_k$ where $k=\overline{2...n}$.

So for $k=n$ we get $f(\pmb M) = f(\{i_1\}) + f(\{i_2\}) + ... + f(\{i_n\}) $. From the fact that $f : \pmb {P(M)} \rightarrow \{0,1,2,...,n\} $ we get that $f(\pmb M) \le n$ and from a) we get that $f(\{i\}) \ge 1 , \forall i \in \pmb M $. Therefore, $n \le f(\{i_1\}) + f(\{i_2\}) + ... + f(\{i_n\}) = f(\pmb M) \le n \implies f(\{i\})=1, \forall i \in \pmb M  $ and $f(\pmb M) = n$.

Replacing in c) we get : $f(\{i_1,i_2,...,i_k\}) = k , \forall i_1,i_2,...,i_k \in \pmb M , i_1 \ne i_2 \ne ... \ne i_k$ where $k=\overline{2...n}$ . So the final solution is $f(\pmb A ) = |\pmb A|, \forall \pmb A  \in \pmb {P(M)}$ which also verifies the initial conditions.

Can you please tell me if my solution is complete and correct? I hope I didn't miss anything. Thank you!

Comment: I believe your solution is correct.